# How to add Inner Xelements of an Xelement to other XElement at some specific position in asp.net

Tags: xelement

This is Xelement("elementExamQuestion ") I have created.

```
XElement elementExamQuestion = new XElement("ExamQuestions",
                                                                                        new XAttribute("id", xmodel.examQuestionID),
                                                                                        new XAttribute("srno", xmodel.examqsrno),                                                                                
                                                                                        new XAttribute("isnegative", masterquesResult.qisnegative == null ? "0" : masterquesResult.qisnegative.ToString()),
                                                                                        new XAttribute("quesstatus", "NV"),                                                                                          
                                                                                    new XElement("QuestionId", dr.questionid.ToString()),
                                                                                    new XElement("QuestionNo", ""),
                                                                                    new XElement("Question", dr.question.ToString().Trim()),

                                                                                **<----At This position----->**

                                                                                 new XElement("TopicId",dr.topicid.ToString()),
                                                                                    new XElement("ExamId", xmodel.GI.CE_examid.ToString().Trim()),                                                                                       
                                                                                    new XElement("TimeTaken",""),
                                                                                    new XElement("UTCQuesTime","")
                                                                                                );
```

Now other Xelement("options")

```
     XElement options = new XElement("options",
                                                        new XElement("OptionA",new XAttribute("value","a"),dr.a.Trim()),
                                                        new XElement("OptionB",new XAttribute("value","b"),dr.b.Trim()),
                                                        new XElement("OptionC",new XAttribute("value","c"),dr.c.Trim()),
                                                        new XElement("OptionD",new XAttribute("value","d"),dr.d.Trim()),
                                                        new XElement("OptionE",new XAttribute("value","e"),dr.e.Trim()),
                                                        new XElement("OptionF",new XAttribute("value","f"),dr.f.Trim()),
                                                        new XElement("OptionG",new XAttribute("value","g"),dr.g.Trim()),
                                                        new XElement("OptionH",new XAttribute("value","h"),dr.h.Trim())
                                                        );
```

I want to insert Xelements optionA, OptionB,Option C upto Option H in Xelement("elementExamQuestion") but after XElement("Question").

If anyone can help me it will be great. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

After research I got exact solution

```
 elementExamQuestion.Descendants("Question").ElementAt(0).AddAfterSelf(options.Elements());
```